# set config params from database in yii 1

Tags: php, yii, config

I have created CRUD for global configuration parameters. I want to apply this parameters value as main config params (main.php).
I have found some way like add value of these parameters to any .inc file and perform read/write operation. Can anybody help me how can I achieve this? I am beginner in yii.

I have created table structure :

```
global_config : 
Field      | Value
pageSize   |  20
admin_email|  admin@example.com
```

main.php file as below :

```
.
.
{

'params' = array(
'pageSize' => 10,
'admin_email' => 'admin@example.com',

);

}
```

.
.

I am using config file as show above, I want to change it dynamically that it should get value from database.

So that I can make changes in config file from front-end side. I don't need to perform open/write action on main.php

Comment: I know that I can access that parameters from config file, but I want to set values of this parameters from database. Let me update my question.

Comment: have a look at http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/304/setting-application-parameters-dynamically-in-the-back-end/ and http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/5647-changing-application-configuration-dynamically/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found solution as per my requirement. I followed given below link from yii forum.

Link : http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/304/setting-application-parameters-dynamically-in-the-back-end/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In yii1 you can use params  you can set this in main.php

```
'params'=>array(

    'your_param'=>'your_value ',
```

...

```
 Yii::app()->params['your_param'];
```

and you can set this  value  like a simple array poplulating the value form database

```
$param['yuor_param' =>$your_db_value];
```

Comment: How can I fetch values from database in main.php? I don't this it's possible. @scaisEdge

Comment: You can fetch the value at the index .. action .. and the eventually assing to the params .. and use the params functionality where you need  ..

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this for `params`.  As `Application` `parameters` are not really meant to be altered and if you change a value, it does not persist across different requests.

These are treated as `constant` in `Yii`, So you can't `define` them after running the `script` as `config` files runs at first as your code runs.